# Windows Mobile - Connect to Internet

Tags: windows-mobile, wifi, gprs

My application is making call to server at regular intervals. This requires internet connection either using Wi-Fi or GPRS.

This works ok when phone is waken (screen light is on). But, as soon as phone lights are off, it makes HttpWebRequest and tried to get Internet connection. Mobile starts connecting to Wi-Fi. But, Application does not wait for establishing connection to Wi-Fi.

1. How can I connect to Wi-Fi or GPRS before making HttpWebRequest?
2. How to specify that I want to connect to Wi-Fi or GPRS?

Answer (score 0):

I think their are two approaches to do:

1. You can create a thread and do sleep/resume activity you want.
2. you can use set timer for particular interval.

Comment: I do not want to make mobile awake all the time. This will consume lot of battery power. I just want to wake it up when I need. So, running continuous thread or timer will eat lot of battery.